# How to use SocketIO with another router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I create NodeJS Express Project with express generator. And I want to use SocketIO but It seems got error with settings.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var http = require('http').Server(router);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});
```

[Client PUG file]
I installed SocketIO with NPM and document said that I can use

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But when I use that it seems that not working so I just use CDN Version of socketIO in client Side.

```
script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js")
```

and This is my client side JS Code

```
$(function () {
    var socket = io();
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
  });
```

And I got some error messages from server console and client console

[Server Side Error]

[image: Server Side Error]

[Client Side Error]

[image: Client Side Error]

I think it's problem from the Server side code with initial code with router something. because All of the sample code are like this

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, try my example

```
var app = require('express')();
const router = express.Router();
app.use('/', router); // attach the router to express app
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```